# Jersey/Grizzly will not support application/json when compiled

Tags: java, maven, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, grizzly

I have a Jersey/Grizzly micro service I'm writing, standard stuff. When I run the micro service from intelij the micro service works happily and my postman test works.

Now, if I compile the source code into a java jar (with all dependencies) and run the java jar the postman test for the API call fails with

415 Unsupported Media Type

Does anyone have an idea why this happens? Pom attached below

http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.dave.bob.rest</groupId>
<artifactId>bob-microservice</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>bob-microservice</name>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
            <version>${jersey.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-http</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-grizzly2-servlet</artifactId>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <finalName>clinrisk-microservice-${project.version}</finalName>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.dave.bob.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals><goal>copy-dependencies</goal></goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.dave.bob.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<properties>
    <jersey.version>2.22.1</jersey.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

As a note, all API calls are Post eg.

```
@POST
@Path("/mike")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiOperation(value = "Calculates mike",
        consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
        response = MikeResults.class)
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 405, message = "Invalid input"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 503, message = "Unable to start Mike"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Unable to calculate results")})

public Response calculateMike(@ApiParam(value = "Input Questions", required = true) MikeInput input) {
```

Also the MikeInput does have `@XmlRootElement` set

suggestions?

Comment: are you `POST`ing as JSON?

Comment: @ScaryWombat yes with the right header